# New site created using site template is showing 2010 design on SP 2013

Tags: 2013, 2010, upgrade, site-template

I upgraded a site collection from SP 2010 to SP 2013. It contain a site template called "My Project Site". There is a web part which creates new site using this site template.

Problem is on 2013 the sites being created have 2010 look and feel. All existing sites that were created on 2010 have 2013 look and feel (after I upgraded site collection) so the problem is only with newly created sites.

I opened manifest.xml file of (My Project Site.wsp) and the SharePointProductVersion property is set to 15.0.4833.1000 (which I fixed yesterday as this was another issue)

How do I fix this issue?

**EDIT**
This is how it looks like. 2010 look and feel and all messed up.[image]

**EDIT**
Two things I noticed.

This is happening with not just custom site template but also with built in site template. In SP 2013 (and probably in 2010 too) there is a OOB template called "Project Site". Even if I create new site based on this template, it has same issue i.e. look and feel is 2010.

Second thing is the URL of those sites.

Existing sites which were already created and which were upgraded when I moved from 2010 to 2013 has following URL structure:

http://server/projects/existingsitename/sitepages/home.aspx

But the new sites that have problem have following URL:

http://server/projects/newsitename/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/default.aspx

If I try to open new site at following URL then it shows error 404 file not found.

http://server/projects/newsitename/sitepages/home.aspx

This /projects/ is actually a subsite and those existingsitename and newsitename are also subsites created under /projects/ site.

Comment: did you update your solutions once you update the manifest files? i think you have to deploy the update solution

Comment: Yes I uploaded that solution again in solutions gallery otherwise before that the site was not even creating. After that site is being created but with 2010 look and feel.

Comment: its not a solution which deployed at server using the install-spsolution? did you use the compatibility paremeter in the command when u create new site collection...via your solution? i am not developer but i worked with them so these kind of question I asked them for troubleshooting

Comment: It's a site template in the form of .wsp. I went to Solutions which is under "Web Designer Galleries" in Site Settings. There is an option called "Upload Solution" where you can upload it and it will be activated.

Comment: did you had a alternate css file under Master Pages settings in 2010? If yes, Is it on/in place in 2013 as well?

Comment: Have you upgraded the site collection. Under Site Collection Administration in Site Settings.

Comment: Updated my question with more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found a clue. There is a solution called "SiteEventReceivers". If I disable this feature in "Site Collection Features" then any new site created based on OOB "Project Site" template has 2013 look and feel.

But when I create new site based on custom "My Project Site" template then it says that this feature "SiteEventReceivers" is missing which need to be enabled.

This solution uses a custom master page.